# if statement get skipped in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a basic application to get value from arguments and display them. I have two files:

1. #### APP.js

   ```
   console.log('application launching');

   const fs = require('fs');
   const yarg = require('yargs');
   const node = require('./node.js')

   var command = yarg.argv;

   if (command === '3' ) {
     console.log("adding note");
     node.addnote(argv.name,argv.title);
   }
   else {
     console.log('invalid');
   }
   ```
2. #### node.js

   ```
   console.log("im up")

   var addnote = (name,title) => {
     console.log('Welcome', title, name);
   };

   module.export = {
     addnote
   }
   ```

This is the output I get when I pass an argument:

> Admins-Mac:node admin$ node app.js --3 Tony Mr
>
> application launching
>
> im up
>
> invalid

If my knowledge is right, the output must be `Welcome Mr Tony`.

I can't figure out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yargs is giving you an object of parameters. So you need to check for

```
if (command[3]) {
    // ...
}
```

However, then we'd have errors here

```
node.addnote(argv.name,argv.title);
```

as you did't pass anything, and neither argv.name is defined nor is argv.title.

So given this command:

```
node app.js --3 --name=Tony --title=Mr
```

You would need this code:

```
let command = yarg.argv;
if (command[3]) {
    console.log("adding note");
    addnote(command.name,command.title);
}
```

Third, you don't require nodejs. It's your environment. Instead, you need to require your file holding the second code block.

```
const addnote = require("./2nd.js");
```

assumed your file is called 2nd.js and is in the same folder.

---

To wrap things up (there were a number of other errors in your code) , here's a working rewrite of your code:

> 1st.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const yarg = require('yargs');
const addnote = require("./2nd.js");

let command = yarg.argv;

if (command[3]) {
    console.log("adding note");
    addnote(command.name, command.title);

}

else {
    console.log('invalid');
}
```

---

> 2nd.js:

```
let addnote = (name,title)=>{
    console.log(`Welcome, ${title} ${name}`);
};

module.exports = addnote;
```

> Run with

```
node 1st.js --3 --name=Tony --title=Mr
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running

```
console.log(command);
```

before the if-statement?

yarg.argv actually returns an array of length yarg.argc, you can index that array to get the values like:

```
yarg.argv[3];
```

Comment: yarg.argv doesn't return an array